# Error 404 with Laravel API in store route

Tags: laravel

I am working with Laravel version 8. I have my route like this:

```
Route::post('/user', 'App\Http\Controllers\api\UserController@store');
```

I have my form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('api/user/store') }}">
        @csrf

        <div class="row mb-3">
           <label for="rut" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Rut') }}</label>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input id="rut" type="text" class="form-control @error('rut') is-invalid @enderror" name="rut" value="{{ old('rut') }}" required autocomplete="rut" autofocus>

                   @error('name')
                      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                      </span>
                  @enderror
             </div>
         </div>
```

I ahve a controller in this path: App\Http\Controllers\api\UserController

My controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    echo 1;
    die();
}

}
```

My route list:

[routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJdJj.png)

When I click submit it display error 404... the route was not found. what could it be?

Comment: try change ```action="{{ url('api/user/store') }}"``` to ```action="{{route('user.store'}}"```

Comment: you should go back here and try to understand the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers .

Comment: first of all, the error is clear: `the route was not found`.  Why? Because it's not in the routes list ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use named route by changing this:

`Route::post('/user', 'App\Http\Controllers\api\UserController@store');`

to

```
Route::post(
    '/user/store',
    [UserController::class, 'store']
)->name('user.store');
```

(make sure to import the UserController class at the top)

Then pass the route in the form action like this:

`<form method="POST" action="{{ route('user.store') }}">`

Comment: Yeah, this should work too

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change form's action to `'/user'`, for verifying your right rules you can check it with artisan command `php artisan route:list`

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing this in your `{{ url('api/user/store') }}`

```
{{ route('user.store', 'user_store')}}
```